# Can the Stackdriver v3 API be queried for Uptime Check data?

Tags: stackdriver

#### Context

The [Stackdriver Monitoring API (v3) docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) show how to [query for data from a specific timeseries](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list)

For example, a query like ( formatted for readability )

```
GET https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{project_id}/timeSeries? 
filter= 
  metric.type="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time" AND 
  metric.label.instance_name = "my-workstation"
&interval.endTime=2017-04-30T08:00:00.000Z 
&interval.startTime=2017-04-30T08:00:00.000Z 
&key=<key>
```

Will return `cpu/usage_time` metrics for `my-workstation`.

#### Question

Can I retrieve data from a [StackDriver Monitoring Uptime Check](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/uptime-checks) via a similar API call?

For example; I've setup a Stackdriver Monitoring Uptime Check to poll `www.mysite.com` every minute.

I'd like to extract the results of that poll from the Stackdriver Monitoring API

What is the correct `filter` to send to the Stackdriver Monitoring API to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

These metrics are currently not available via the Stackdriver Monitoring API, but exposing them is on our roadmap. Stay tuned.